# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined, cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call 'reload'

Tags: jquery, masonry

Please help me to figure out what is the issue, I'm getting two errors

> 1.Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined
>
> 2.cannot call methods on masonry prior to initialization; attempted to call 'reload'.

Javascript

```
$("#articleview").append(articles);
initialiseMasonry();
function initialiseMasonry() {
    $('#articleview').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.masonry_thumbnail',
        //columnWidth: 580,
        isAnimated: true,
    }).imagesLoaded(function () {
        hideLoadingImg(true);
        $(this).masonry('reload');
    });
}
```

I'm appending articles in articleview and getting in html by id.

Comment: post your full code or give the link of example

Comment: what is the content of `articles`?

Comment: and please show your HTML structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the errors point the sane thing that the selector "#articleview" is returning null and hence element of null is undefined and masonry function is also called on null which is throwing second error. Possible causes -
1. There is no html element with id "articleview".
2. Script loads before dom is loaded and hence script cannot find the element.